# Classify people, predict event

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series

Let's pretend we have a series of events, which have binary results $ y_1, \ldots, y_n $.

For every event we have a number of people with more or less stable features $ f_1, \ldots, f_k $ (like sex for given client for every event) and a volatile feature $ g $ (for instance, the amount of spent money for the corresponding event).

We want to predict the target $ y_t $ using this data. Empirically we found that values like $$ \sum \{ g | f_1 > c \} $$ have some predictive power and want to generalize them (in both ways, using different conditions and different aggregations).

What kind of machine learning algorithm can be useful for this setting?

The problem is, essentially, that we want to find a cluster based on features $ f_1, \ldots, f_k $ that have predictive power in terms of feature $ g $.

Comment: Can we get a snippet of the data, as an example. I would however suggest some regression to see which feature f has the most impact on g.